# Upstart не запускает nginx

Tags: nginx, service, автозагрузка

Помогите разобраться. В системе Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago) стоит init upstart:

```
rpm -qf /sbin/init
upstart-0.6.5-13.el6_5.3.x86_64
```

Но не смотря на присутствие файла /etc/init/nginx.conf:

```
cat /etc/init/nginx.conf

# nginx

description "nginx http daemon"
author "George Shammas <georgyo@gmail.com>"

# start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=!lo)
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

env DAEMON=/usr/sbin/nginx
env PID=/var/run/nginx.pid

expect fork
respawn
respawn limit 10 5
#oom never

pre-start script
        $DAEMON -t
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                then exit $?
        fi
end script

exec $DAEMON
```

NGINX после перезагрузки не стартует:

```
initctl status nginx
nginx stop/waiting
```

Раньше был /etc/init.d/nginx файл, и при добавлении его в автозапуск -  стартовал:

```
chkconfig nginx on
```

Но это System V поведение, и мне не совсем понятен где тут мост от Upstart к нему. Ведь работают chkconfig, и скрипты из /etc/init.d запускаются. Кто их запускает не ясно (`/etc/init.d/rc` не нашёл). 
Но это потом. Сейчас не могу понять почему при наличии в папке `/etc/init/nginx.conf` и записи `start on runlevel [2345]` nginx не стартует.

Мне хочет использовать именно Upstart autostart потому что в `/etc/init/nginx.conf` есть возможность автоматического respawn при крахе (не дай Бог)).

Comment: А `initctrl start nginx` запускает?

Comment: Запускает, но не запускать же мне его каждый раз вручную.

Comment: А другие сервисы из `/etc/init/` запускаются?

Comment: Да, например /etc/init/tty.conf

Comment: Пробовал послать `initctl emit runlevel=3` чтоб сымитировать такое событие в системе но nginx не запустился.

Comment: Посмотрите в `/var/log/upstart`, может там есть логи?

Comment: В Ubuntu, кстати, `start on filesystem and static-network-up`

Comment: Ну вон я закоментил, вдруг этих событий нет в redhat, поставил то что точно должно быть.

Comment: Такого файла нет, единственное что вызывает подозрения это `init: /etc/init.conf: Unable to load configuration: No such file or directory` в `/var/log/messages` после `initctl reload-configuration`